# Is net.sf.json.JSONArray compatible with org.json.JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays, org.json

I am trying to use some of the json conversion methods available in net.sf.json.JSONArray and net.sf.json.JSONObject but it appears these objects are not compatible with (Androids) org.json.JSONArray and org.json.JSONObject objects. Essentially what I am looking for is an efficient and easy way to transform a valid JSON String into Java objects like Arrays. The net.sf.json package objects appear to have such conversion methods.

My question is - Is net.sf.json.JSONArray compatible with org.json.JSONArray and if so how can these objects be used? Attempting to cast from one to the other gets me nowhere.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray = orgJSONArray; 
jsonArray = (JSONArray)orgJSONArray;
```

If I can't use net.sf.json with org.json objects, in the realm of Android what is the best and most efficient way to convert a valid JSON string to a Java Array object.

Comment: Copy those libs to your project lib and change import statements to net.sf.json... AFAIK it should work.

Comment: attempting this the immediate down side appears to be you have to abandon all android json objects and associated functions because they are bound to objects spawned from org.json.

Comment: yes, at a time you can use either one of those libraries only.

Answer (score 2):

By definition `net.sf.json.JSONObject` is not "compatible" with `org.json.JSONObject` unless one is a subclass of the other.  Even if the two classes were to have word-for-word identical definitions, the different package names would make them totally different and incompatible classes.

Comment: I understand....... it's a challenge. How about using the net.sf.json objects as custom objects with the org.json.JSONObject and org.json.JSONArray as their superclasses?

Comment: @StephenBennett -- Then you'd have to edit and recompile net.sf.json.

Comment: I was hoping there would be some kind of interoperability layer.